# Press Twice to exit the activity not working

Tags: java, android

i need to close and activity and start another only when the user presses back twice. I am using this code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
        Log.e("Entering","Yes");
        DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(AddBreakfastActivity.this);
        db.deleteTodaysUnsavedMenu(Integer.parseInt(newDay),Integer.parseInt(newIntMonth));
        Intent intent=new Intent(AddBreakfastActivity.this,ProvidersUpdateActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
    else {
        this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
        Log.e("BOOLEANVALUE", String.valueOf(doubleBackToExitPressedOnce));
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
            }
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

On pressing back once the app exits and shows the Toast message.
It doesnt wait for the second press. How can i resolve this?
Thank you.

**EDIT**

Found it to be working as expected when the back button is pressed. However shows aforesaid issue when called from

```
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if(id==android.R.id.home){
            onBackPressed();
        }
}
```

Comment: do you set `doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false` by default?

Comment: yes i did , The code does enter the else part as i am able to receive the boolean value in log and also the toast message. But after that the app exits without any stack trace for such behavior.

Comment: try put `super.onBackPressed();
        return;` inside if statement

Comment: The person who down voted the question. Please state the reason for down voting. Form where i see it , its not a duplicate or off topic, and has the code attached. Your reply might help me post better questions in future.

Comment: @Pranjal Can you show declaration of `doubleBackToExitPressedOnce` as well ?

Answer (score 1):

you can also do this with on keydown event as code below remove backpressed

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        if(event.getAction()==KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN && keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
        {
            if (doubleBackToExitPressedOnce) {
                Log.e("Entering","Yes");
                DatabaseHandler db=new DatabaseHandler(AddBreakfastActivity.this);
                db.deleteTodaysUnsavedMenu(Integer.parseInt(newDay),Integer.parseInt(newIntMonth));
                Intent intent=new Intent(AddBreakfastActivity.this,ProvidersUpdateActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            else {
                this.doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = true;
                Log.e("BOOLEANVALUE", String.valueOf(doubleBackToExitPressedOnce));
                Toast.makeText(this, "Please click BACK again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        doubleBackToExitPressedOnce = false;
                    }
                }, 2000);
                return false;
        }
}
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of "Press Twice to Exit" with fragments:

```
boolean doublePressToQuit = false;    
@Override
        public void onBackPressed() {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
                getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            } else {
                if (doublePressToQuit) {
                    DashBoardActivity.this.finish();
                } else {
                    this.doublePressToQuit = true;
                    Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.quit_notification), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            doublePressToQuit = false;
                        }
                    }, 2000);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Include `super.onBackPressed();` inside your `IF` statement to override the `onBackPressed()` event.

Comment: Tried it but it didnt work.The app is still exiting on single backpressed.Its not even entering in the  if block.

Comment: try remove or make all the code inside `IF` statement to comment and add ` super.onBackPressed();` into it, which mean only 1 line of code inside `IF` statement

Comment: ok i have done that , but it didnt work.The issue isnt with if block , the if block is to be executed on the second click on the backpress. On the first click the else part is executed. So if i am not wrong the issue should be somewhere in the else part?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code, it works for me

```
boolean firstBackPressed = false;
.
.
.
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (!firstBackPressed) {
            firstBackPressed = true;
            Toast.makeText(MainMenu.this, "Press back again to exit", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Please find this

```
  private boolean isShownExit;

 @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {

        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(Gravity.LEFT)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
            isShownExit = false;
            return;
        } else {
            if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1) {              
                    if (!isShownExit) {
                        isShownExit = true;
                        showToast(this, "Press again to exit");
                    } else {
                        hideSoftKeyboardDialogDismiss(this);
                        startAnotherActivityHereWhichDoYouwant();
                }
            } else {
               getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        }
    }
```